# solving for $x^{\ln{(x)}}=1$

Tags: solution-verification

I think that I solved this equation, but there is still some dillema didi I did it right.

Can you please check my solution, and see did I make any mistakes, and maybe propose another solution.

$$
x^{\ln{(x)}}=1\\
\ln(x^{\ln{(x)}})=\ln(1)\\
\text{I can write $\ln(x^{\ln{(x)}})$ as $\ln(x)*\ln(x)\implies2\ln(x)$ and}\\
\text{$\ln(1)\ as\ 0$, so}\\
2\ln(x)=0\\
\text{divide both sides with 2}\\
\ln(x)=0\\
\text{raising both sides to $e$}\\
e^{\ln(x)=e^0}\\
x=1\\
$$

Thanks.

Comment: why $ln(x)*ln(x) = 2 ln(x)$?

Comment: Careful!! $\ln(x^2) = 2\ln(x)~~$ **BUT** $~~(\ln x)^2\neq \ln(x^2)$!! The final result is correct, but it comes from the fact that
$$
(\ln x)^2 = 0
$$
which implies $\ln x = 0$ and so on, and **not** from
$$
2\ln x = 0
$$

Comment: $\ln(x) * \ln(x) = 2\ln(x) \implies x = e^2$ or $x = 1$, so it implies that it correct, but its not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After what Andrea T wrote you are correctb,but you can do it more easily by reaching at the step $\ln^2(x)=0 \implies \ln x=0\implies x=1$ because $\ln x$ is one-to-one function.

Answer (score 6):

$$\ln x\cdot \ln x = (\ln x)^2\neq \ln(x^2) = 2\ln x$$

So what you have, instead, is $$(\ln x)^2 = \ln(1) = 0$$

Then, we **do have** that $(\ln x)^2 = 0 \implies \ln x = 0 \implies e^{\ln x}  = e^0 = 1 \iff x = 1$

Comment: @amWhy: I like direct and clean answers +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing complex solutions, there are more.

$$\begin{align}
&&x^{\ln(x)}&=1\\
\implies&& e^{\left(\ln(x)\right)^2}&=1\\
\implies&&\left(\ln(x)\right)^2 &=2\pi i n&\mbox{where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
\implies&& x&=e^{\pm\sqrt{2\pi i n}}\\
\implies&& x&=e^{\pm\sqrt{2\pi i n}}
\end{align}$$

This can be further broken down into the form $e^A\left(\cos(B)+i\cos(C)\right)$ when you consider positive/negative values for $n$ and what $\pm\sqrt{\pm i}$ is.

Comment: I think you should at least mention that $x\mapsto x^{\ln x}$ is not defined as a (single-valued) function for $x\in\Bbb C$, so these (for $x\neq1$) are only weak solutions, in the sense that one of the many possible values one could associate to the expression $x^{\ln x}$ equals $1$.